# Is it possible to import frame #n of video without iteration\importing all the frames in Python?

Tags: python, image-processing, video-processing

I was using `skvideo` library  to extract all frames of the videofiles in two ways. For the relatively small videos, I was extracting the whole video as an np-array:

 `videodata = skvideo.io.vread(videofile)`
And for bigger ones I was using generator and doing iteration of frames, and running some calculations on each frame separately, to not have issues with memory:

```
videogen=skvideo.io.vreader(videofile)
for frame in videogen:
        param=calc_func(frame)
```

However, sometimes I would like to access just a single frame #n without a need to load all of them. So far the only way I see is to break the loop once iteration index 'i==n', and if the number n is high, then it still requires iterating over a lot of frames. So I am wondering if there is faster way to do this, by just specifying needed frame to extract from video.

Comment: You might look into `pims`. It has this capability

Comment: Depending on the codec in the video, you would still need to iterate video from the last key-frame and forward until the specified frame. This is because not all frames contain all the information for compression reasons. Just a heads up.